# Can not import OwnerService from another module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin

[image]

I can't create an owner service in my DataLoader class because I can't import package from pet-clinic-data. I added the dependency of data package to web's pom.xml, but still I can't import that service.

This is what pet-clinic-data pom.xml looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>sfg-pet-clinic</artifactId>
        <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>pet-clinic-data</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring-boot.repackage.skip>true</spring-boot.repackage.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

This is what pet-clinic-web pom.xml looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>sfg-pet-clinic</artifactId>
        <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>pet-clinic-web</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>pet-clinic-data</artifactId>
            <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>pet-clinic-data</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Can someone explain why I can't import the package even though I already declared the dependency in the pom.xml?

Still can't solve the issue!

Comment: Have you tried `mvn install` for `pet-clinic-data` project?
`pet-clinic-data` artifact (in our case jar file) should exist somewhere (for example, in your local maven repo, and you can put it there by executing `mvn install`). IDEa doesn't look at the source code, it need an artifact

Comment: @Flame239 I did that. Build succeeded but still can't import it.

Comment: Does this jar exist in local `.m2` repo and does IntelliJ idea sees it under `External Libraries`?

Comment: @Flame239 jar exists in .m2 repo but it is not under External Libraries

Comment: Could you manually add `import ....OwnerService` in `DataLoader` class and then execute `mvn clean compile`

Comment: Please paste the output

Comment: @Flame239 It failed to execute with an error message "variable ownerService might not have been initialized".

Comment: You can fix it by removing empty constructor

Comment: @Flame239 build succeeded when I assigned null to ownerService but still it can't resolve  symbol.

Comment: please paste mvn output

Comment: or you mean maven command was successful but IDEa still highlights it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246023/discussion-between-epitaph-and-flame239).